# AEM: Iterating deep level nodes in Sightly ( with multfield )

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly

I have Slightly code something like this:

```java
   <ul class="topnav" data-sly-   use.topnav="com.company.companysite.util.myJavaClass" data-sly-list="${topnav.getPathValueMap}">
   <li>${!item}></li>  ( what do I put here?? )
</ul>
```

and a java use class method like this:

```java
public ValueMap getPathValueMap() {
       String parentPath = "/content/siteregion/en/jcr:content/toplevel/regionNames";
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = getResourceResolver();
    Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(parentPath);
    ValueMap vm = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(resource);
    return vm;

}
```

**QUESTION:**  I have a multifield dialog at level /content/siteregion/en/jcr:content/toplevel/regionNames

I need Slightly code to iterate the values the user put in the multifield dialog

Comment: What values do you have in the multifield? And if you already are using a class, I would recommend to do the processing there and return a List for this multifield. With your example I think you would only iterate over all the properties of the node.

Comment: right - I actually got it working returning a hashmap to sightly - do you know how to get the key and/or value from sightly - so this works  ${!item} but I want to do something like ${!item.getValue}  ?  right now with ${!item}  I only get the key from the hashmap not the value

Comment: have you tried using ${item.key} and ${item.value}?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Sightly Intro Part 3](http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2014/03/sightly-intro-part3.html) something like this should work for iterating Maps:

```
<ul class="topnav" data-sly-use.topnav="com.company.companysite.util.myJavaClass" data-sly-list.pathMap="${topnav.getPathValueMap}">
    <li>${pathMap} : ${topnav.getPathValueMap[pathMap]}</li>
</ul>
```